# Define active window for startup in .vimrc

Tags: vimrc, vim-windows

I have the following line in my .vimrc to open [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) on startup:

```
NERDTreeToggle
```

Now, if I start vim, I have NERDTree on the left and the file I opened on the right.

The left window is focused on startup. How can I put the focus on the right window on startup?

Comment: I don't have NERDTree installed, so I can't test it, but does `au VimEnter * wincmd l` work?

Comment: Do you really have that command in your .vimrc? That shouldn't yet be available when Vim starts up.

Comment: I load *"NERDTree"* with *"vim-plug"* (a package manager for vim). This line in my `.vimrc` loads NT immediately: `Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on': 'NERDTreeToggle' }`, so I can use `NERDTreeToggl` in `.vimrc`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with a simple autocommand:

```
au VimEnter * wincmd l
```

This tells vim anytime you open a new vim window (`VimEnter`) on any file type `*` to run the ex command `:wincmd l`. `wincmd l` is effectively the same thing as pressing `<C-w>l` in normal mode, which moves you one split to the right. From `:h ctrl_w-l`

```
CTRL-W CTRL-L                   *CTRL-W_CTRL-L* *CTRL-W_l*
CTRL-W l    Move cursor to Nth window right of current one.  Uses the
        cursor position to select between alternatives.
```